# Laravel - Variable inside a create returns 0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is the problem in my code. i have this Model. the parameters passed are `$uid=1` and `$id=1`.
But here is my problem. when i call the `create` it inserts 0 and 0 as the value of pid and uid.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cart extends Model
{

  protected $table = 'cart';
  protected $fillable = [
      'pid', 'uid'
  ];

  public $uid=0;
  public function __construct($uid)
  {
    $this->uid=$uid;
    var_dump($this->uid); // int(1) array(2) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" ["uid"]=> int(1) }
  }

  public function add($id)
  {
    $cart = $this::create(['pid' => $id,'uid' => $this->uid]);
    $cart->save();
    var_dump($id,$this->uid); //string(1) "1" int(1)
  }



}
```

Here is the `var_dump` of my output view.

```
int(1) array(2) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" ["uid"]=> int(1) } string(1) "1" int(1)
```

I am a beginner in Laravel and i have referred the laravel documentation which doesn't help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are unecessary as models already have methods behind the scenes that interact with the database, which is what a ORM is. Remove both methods you have added and add this logic to your controller.

Make sure you use the namespace at the top of your controller first

```
use App\Cart;
```

Now in your controller method

```
$cart = new Cart;
$cart->uid = $request->uid;
$cart->pid = $request->pid;
$cart->save();
```

You can the retrieve the cart id by $cart->id